# Are Spring Framework Security Vulnerabilities CVEs applicable to Grails

Tags: spring, security, grails

Some vulnerabilities that apply to Spring Framework for versions are included in my Grails deployments. Are these also vulnerabilities in Grails (v2.2.5 which contains Spring 3.1.4)? The vulnerabilities listed here

http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-9664/product_id-17274/Springsource-Spring-Framework.html

apply to e.g. Spring v 3.0.0 to 3.2.8 which includes 3.1.4 but Grails 2.2.5 is the latest release of 2.2.x.

How do I know if these CVEs apply to my version of Grails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring, Grails, and Groovy teams have been part of the same company since 2008 when SpringSource (sadly no longer an entity) bought G2One, continuing with the purchase of SpringSource by VMware, and the dissolution of SpringSource into Pivotal when it was formed from groups from EMC and VMware. They work together closely and of course the Spring team notifies the Grails team when vulnerabilities arise.

The issues in the page you linked to are either non-issues in Grails, or are old enough that any recent version of Grails uses a version of Spring that has a fix for the issue. Specifically, CVE-2014-1904 deals with web/servlet/tags/form/FormTag.java, but while JSP tags are supported in Grails, they're rarely used since GSP tags and includes are vastly more convenient. CVE-2014-0054, CVE-2013-7315, and CVE-2013-4152 relate to StAX/OXM/JAXB/XXE - a handful of XML-based acronyms that have no direct support in Grails, and to my knowledge no (or little if any) plugin support. CVE-2013-6429 discusses SourceHttpMessageConverter which doesn't seem to be directly used, but is potentially used by `RestTemplate` and therefore potentially by the rest-client-builder plugin.

But if these were issues, the Grails team would be notified and the issues would be addressed. This has happened a few times in the past, e.g. http://support.springsource.com/security/cve-2012-1833. Grails-specific issues are also reported using the same mechanism, e.g. http://www.pivotal.io/security/cve-2014-0053

Comment: thanks - that was exactly my issue - I could not find many Grails CVEs. In my case I am using Grails 2.2.5 which contain a Spring  that is almost 2 years old so I plan to upgrade. Thanks for the clarification of how the teams are organised very useful.